# Photo tags query response of max 400 elements

Tags: facebook, limit, photo

i'm using new Facebook SDK 3.0 but it's not relevant since Graph API Explorer has the same behavior.
The problem is that when i try to fetch some user photo tags, like "me/photos" or the equivalent FQL query, i get a response of max 400 elements, using either graph or fql.
I already tried using LIMIT field (for example the FQL query is "SELECT src, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me() LIMIT 1000) LIMIT 1000")
but nothing change.
I also tried with SINCE and UNTIL, but i understood that FB returns a table of 400 rows and then shrink it according to your query.

Is maybe another way to bypass this limit or for some unknown reason FB wanted it and it's not a bug?

Thank you

Comment: First, are you sure you've been tagged on more than 400 photos?

Comment: of course, i tried also with friends' tags. it's not a problem on my side...